# WiX Bootstrapper - Install MS KB package

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm creating a WiX Bootstrapper for my application (running on a Window 2012 Server). My application requires Visual C++ 2015, KB2919355 and KB2919442.

So I created the part for both packages :

```
<!-- Update for windows server 2012 : KB2919442 -->
<PackageGroup Id="KB2919442">
  <MsuPackage Cache="no"
              Compressed="no"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              Name="Redist\KB2919442-x64.msu"
              SourceFile=".\Resources\Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu"
              DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/8/CF821C31-38C7-4C5C-89BB-B283059269AF/Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu"
              InstallCommand="/install">
  </MsuPackage>
</PackageGroup>

<!-- Update for windows server 2012 : KB2919355 -->
<PackageGroup Id="KB2919355">
  <MsuPackage Cache="no"
              Compressed="no"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              Name="Redist\KB2919355-x64.msu"
              SourceFile=".\Resources\Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu"
              DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/6/256CCCFB-5341-4A8D-A277-8A81B21A1E35/Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu"
              InstallCommand="/install">
  </MsuPackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

It works good (install for 700Mo KB2919355 is very long) but when I do a software update, my bootstrapper tries to reinstall the packages.

**How can I detect if packages are required ?**

Comment: I updated the section on extracting WiX bundles.

Comment: Hi. Just wondering if you can share the `DetectCondition` and relevant variables that are able to detect if the msus are already installed? Thank you!

Comment: @RamiA. I'm sorry but I can't. I am on a new job and I have no access to source code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I haven't used this feature, but did you investigate the
>   **`DetectCondition`** attribute of the [**`MsuPackage Element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msupackage.html)?
>   There is also the **`InstallCondition`** attribute which you should
>   investigate.

***DetectCondition***: "*A condition that determines if the package is present on the target system. This condition can use built-in variables and variables returned by searches. This condition is necessary because Windows doesn't provide a method to detect the presence of an MsuPackage. Burn uses this condition to determine how to treat this package during a bundle action; for example, if this condition is false or omitted and the bundle is being installed, Burn will install this package.*"

***InstallCondition***: "*A condition to evaluate before installing the package. The package will only be installed if the condition evaluates to true. If the condition evaluates to false and the bundle is being installed, repaired, or modified, the package will be uninstalled.*"

---

***Server Deployment***: For the record (not to preach too much), but server deployment is very dangerous, you are essentially dealing with single points of failure (or recoverable server virtuals - which you no doubt use for your testing).

For a server install I might choose to check for the presence of such an update, and if it is missing just abort telling the user to install the update via Windows Update or some other deployment mechanism ([it looks like there is something special about these updates](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/137874-install-windows-server-2012-r2-update-1-kb2919355)). The overall idea is to not deliver outdated runtimes. If you have reliable download links you can provide them.

Alternatively I deliver the setup "in pieces" with all runtimes and prerequisites separate from the main application installer. Believe it or not but I prefer just a ZIP file. Then I deliver a **single page PDF** describing how to get things running, or I deliver **a link to a web page** (your own web-page) with deployment information for the application. This way I can maintain the installation information in an "hotfixable" format and update users on any new pending deployment lunacy :-). You can link to a PDF of course. ***`And crucially you can maintain appropriate download links for the prerequisites - if this is something you have the resources to do`***.

---

***Burn Bundle Extract***:

And here is a **technical tidbit**. You can now extract the contents from a WiX bundle as follows (you need the WiX toolkit installed - unfortunately - in order to have `dark.exe` available - for other users reading this: [download WiX toolkit here](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/)):

```
dark.exe -x outputfolder setup.exe
```

I would add this to your documentation - so your users can disassemble your **`setup.exe`** and get to its "pieces" as described above. Just open a command prompt, CD to the folder where the **`setup.exe`** resides. Then specify the above command. The output folder will contain a couple of sub-folders containing both extracted MSI, MSU and EXE files and manifests and resource file for the Burn GUI.